# Git clone from another server

Tags: git, ssh

*Upfront: I'm lacking in git skills and I searched for the requisite commands, but unfortunately didn't work*

I have a remote server A which I access using `ssh` and the files are at `cd /var/www/html` location. I'm coming up with another server B in which I need to clone the git from Server A. I tried a few commands for setting it up on B, which I access using ssh only,  but the latest one was 
`git clone git+ssh://user@serverA.com/var/www/html` but this lead to below error:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Can someone please provide step by step details on how to set up the clone.
PS: I only ran the `git clone` commands. Not sure if I need to run `git init` and other commands

Comment: Just copy the `.git` directory to server B using ordinary means (an ftp/ssh client such as FileZilla). You can zip/rar it since it has a lot of files.

Comment: may I know the reason for downvote?